# Why is RowIndex in WinForms DataGridView always -1 after a filter is set?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'd like to have a WinForms DataGridView (datasource = DataTable) where the user can select multiple checkbox cells and enable/disable those by pressing the space key. This works fine as long as no filter is applied. Once I do this the row index is -1 and I can not select the selected cells by pressing the space bar.

[image: My datagridview. Filter can be seen on the left]

This is the code I use to enable selection of multiple cells by pressing the space bar.

```
private void grdChannels_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string currentRowFilter = (grdChannels.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter;
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection selectedCells = grdChannels.SelectedCells;
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedCells.Count; i++)
        {
            if (selectedCells[i].RowIndex == -1)
                continue;   // Why do we get here if a RowFilter was added?
            DataGridViewCell selectedCell = selectedCells[i];
            if (!(selectedCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell))
                continue;
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell selectedCheckBoxCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)selectedCell;
            string cellVal = selectedCheckBoxCell.Value?.ToString();
            bool currentCellVal = bool.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellVal) ? "False" : cellVal);
            selectedCheckBoxCell.Value = !currentCellVal;
        }
        grdChannels.BindingContext[grdChannels.DataSource].EndCurrentEdit();
    }
}
```

This is the code I use to set/reset the filter on my datagrid (grdChannels):

```
if (grdChannels.Columns[node.Key] != null)
    (grdChannels.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] = true", node.Key.Trim());
else
    (grdChannels.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = null;
```

I also had to add this code in order to update my datagridview the moment it is changed:

```
private void grdChannels_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     // this is needed as cell values won't be commited as long as user doesn't change row or hits enter
     grdChannels.BindingContext[grdChannels.DataSource].EndCurrentEdit();
}

private void grdChannels_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grdChannels.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```

Once the user clicked on a checkbox in a filtered view the row does get an index and everything works as expected. But if the user first uses the space bar the index is always -1. How can i fix this?

Comment: This, if I recall correctly, is something to do with the focus being on the DataGrid rather than the checkbox. I think you can change the tab focus to enable the keyboard controls to select the right part. Sorry if this is vague but it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks but from what I can tell this doesn't seem to be the issue. Once I change the value of a checkbox the row gets an index and my code works fine. No matter if I use mouse click or if I hit space to do this. However the code in my keyUp event (change value of multiple checkboxes at once by pressing space) needs a row index to work. The focus doesn't make a difference as long as I don't change a checkbox value first.